# Swift how to add hyperlink to a button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So, I am trying when i click the button to open a link of a website but its not working for some reason. I have watched video from 2020 and for the guy worked but for me it gives me errors here is an image of the errors.

[image: Errors]

And here is the code

```
import UIKit

class ContactViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func FB(_ sender: Any) {

}
@IBAction func YT(_ sender: Any) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "www.google.com")!)
}
@IBAction func URL(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBAction func CALL(_ sender: Any) {
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I want for every button to have link only the one CALL named to have a phone number and to direct into the phone diler.

EDIT

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of force casting use this code

```
@IBAction func YT(_ sender: Any) {

      if let url = URL(string: "www.google.com") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
      } else {
        print("url is not correct")
      }


    }


@IBAction func CALL(_ sender: Any) {
if let url = URL(string: "telprompt://\(phoneNumber)") {
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        guard application.canOpenURL(url) else {
            return
        }
        application.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

For Email import MessageUI

```
import MessageUI
@IBAction func Email(_ sender: Any) {
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mail.setToRecipients(["you@yoursite.com"])
        mail.setMessageBody("<p>You're so awesome!</p>", isHTML: true)

        present(mail, animated: true)
    } else {
        // show failure alert
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i make to send mail aswell when i click a button to take me to mail and send to a specific email?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213521/discussion-between-klayj-and-jawadali).